# Is there such a thing as truly plain HTML?

Tags: browser, html, website, css

I am just learning about HTML basics and browser styling and I was struck by the question in the title: even for HTML written (as, I think, the HTML5 standard asks) purely with semantic elements, does one ever see "plain HTML" or is there always going to be some default browser styling (which, presumably, differs browser to browser) for these files?

That is, if plain HTML consists only in semantic elements, does it even make sense to talk about plain HTML or is there always going to be some layer which translates the tags and overall elements according to some "presentation rule"?

I have read briefly about things like reset.css but it's not clear to me why those are brought up as "plain".

Comment: HTML is for structure. think of it like "style" is a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does one ever see "plain HTML" or is there always going to be some default browser styling (which, presumably, differs browser to browser) for these files?

There is always going to be some default browser styling. Without there being some default browser styling, all elements would be invisible.

But that's exactly what "plain HTML" means – it doesn't mean that there is *no* styling whatsoever; rather, it means that all of the styling comes from **somewhere else than the HTML page.** The browser is not part of the HTML markup that you wrote, so the "default browser styling" is also not part of the HTML you wrote – the markup reports only the semantics to the browser, and each browser decides on some suitable default style.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! As a follow up, is there any reason then that many sources seem to bring up CSS reset in the context of these sorts of questions? Is it just some default CSS code which captures what we mean by the vague notion of "plain" (and such that we aren't at the mercy of potential differences in defaults across browsers)?

Comment: I've not used it myself, but as I understand it, it has nothing to do with "plain" in the usual sense, but the goal is specifically to give an _empty_ "all zeros" stylesheet ([like this one](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)) for you to build on top of. Whereas a stylesheet that just defines some generic "plain style" doesn't really count as a CSS 'reset' at all – it's just a stylesheet.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you again!